# Using Regex in F# to Filter Strings

Tags: regex, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to use regex to filter all the strings in a list of strings. Here is my function which takes a string and filters it

```
let filterWord wordToFilter = 
    Regex.Replace(wordToFilter, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/!\'?.-]", "");
```

Since I want to apply that function to every element in my list of strings, it seems that using List.map would make sense. Here is my attempt at using map

```
let filteredWords = unfilteredWords |> List.map(fun x -> filterWord(x));
```

I was hoping that line would apply my filter function to every string in my list (unfilteredWords is a list of strings) but instead I get a syntax error saying

```
"Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string [] -> 'a    
but given a
    'b list -> 'c list    
The type 'string []' does not match the type ''a list'"
```

And have no idea why. Here is the full code

```
open System;
open System.IO;
open System.Text.RegularExpressions;

(*Tests if an element is in a list*)
let isInList elementToFind listToCheck = 
    List.fold(fun a b -> a || b = elementToFind) false listToCheck;

(*Takes a string and filters it down to common text characters*)
let filterWord wordToFilter = 
    Regex.Replace(wordToFilter, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/!\'?.-]", "");

(*Main method of the program*)
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argsv =
    let input = File.ReadAllText("Alice in Wonderland.txt"); //Reads all the text into a single string
    let unfilteredWords = input.Split(' ');
    let filteredWords = unfilteredWords |> List.map(fun x -> filterWord(x));
    0;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Apparently changing the value of unfilteredWords to a hard coded string array fixes it. Problem is I have no idea how to make it work with split.

Comment: As an aside, put a `+` at the end of your regex, just after the `]`, to optimize the replacement process somewhat.

Comment: I think you need to post full relevant code. How is `unfilteredWords` declared?

Comment: Works on my machine. What does your `unfilteredWords` look like?

Comment: error message says **string []** so there must be a string **array** (not list) somewhere to mess things up (probably unfilteredWords)

Comment: Have a look at the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Z7gZMj). I hope it will help.

Comment: I suspect that Array.map would work here because of how the input is declared

Comment: I added the full code, thanks for your comments so far

Comment: @NickG: I added a working demo to my answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix: use `Array.map` instead of `List.map`.

Note that you can use F# `.Split [|' '|]` instead of `.Split(' ')`.

```
let input = "### $$$ Alice In Wonderland ,,,,";
let unfilteredWords = input.Split [|' '|]
let filteredWords = unfilteredWords |> Array.map(fun x -> filterWord(x));
printfn "%A" filteredWords;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/dc8XJG)

The output for the sample string in my demo is

```
[|""; ""; "Alice"; "In"; "Wonderland"; ""|]
```

Answer (score -1):

Seeing this question:
[F# Using List.map on an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333488/f-using-list-map-on-an-array-of-strings)

I would guess you should use Array.map or Seq.map instead of List.map