# F# Using List.map on an array of strings

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to use F#'s List.map function to call a function I've written on every string in the array. Here is the function I've written

```
(*Takes a string and filters it down to common text characters*)
let filterWord wordToFilter = 
    Regex.Replace(wordToFilter, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/!\'?.-]", "");
```

and here is my main method where I call it

```
(*Main method of the program*)
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argsv =
    let input = File.ReadAllText("Alice in Wonderland.txt"); //Reads all the text into a single string
    let unfilteredWords = input.Split(' ');
    let filteredWords = unfilteredWords |> List.map(fun x -> filterWord(x));
    0;
```

The problem is I am getting a syntax error at my List.map call saying

```
Error       Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string [] -> 'a    
but given a
    'b list -> 'c list    
The type 'string []' does not match the type ''a list'
```

Changing input.split to a hard coded string array fixes the error so it has something to do with F# not realizing the result of input.split can be used with the map function as it's a string array. I just don't know how to change the code so it accomplishes what I want to accomplish. I'm relatively new to F# so any help I can get would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> F# not realizing the result of input.split can be used with the map function as it's a string array

`List.map` works on `list`s, so F# realizes the result *can't* be used with `List.map`. Use [`Array.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353512.aspx) (which works on arrays) instead.